# Spring boot json error media type and spring security

Tags: java, json, spring, security, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot (tomcat) REST controller declared as `produces = "text/plain"`. My application uses spring security. If I send a request that will result in a 403 then the default spring boot json error handler will try to return a `Content-Type` of `application/json`.

This results in the client actually getting a `406` error `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` because the client specified `Accept: text/plain` in the request.

The obvious answer is to ask the client to specify two `Accept` headers with `text/plain` and `application/json`. Doesn't work, you still get the `406`. Doesn't work either with a single, multi-valued header separated by commas.

In all cases the `403` survives all the way to `StandardHostValve.status()` along with the two `Accept` headers in the request but fails somewhere in the default error page forwarder.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your client includes only `application/json` in the accepts request header, does it work?

Comment: It does when the method itself produces `application/json`. If it produces anything else then no, 406 is the result - and that's generated before the 403.

Comment: Hi @AndyBrown, I am facing exactly this same issue. Do you remember how did you solved it?

Comment: @y.luis We added both possible values to the produces field. i.e. `produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE}`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @AndyBrown. I went for another solution which I describe as an answer in case it works for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

What I did, based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42843551/3286487), was to add a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` which sets the response status and writes to it:

```
@Component
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        response.getWriter().write(accessDeniedException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and configure it on the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApiWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    //...

    @Autowired
    private CustomAccessDeniedHandler customAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler);
    }
}
```

Thus returning `Content-Type: text/plain` independently on the `Accept` request header.