# Properly handle access denied in basic authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a pretty normal spring security setup (using spring boot) where all the form login is using a ajax based approach (no redirect, etc), and this is working fine for form login.

For basic authentication I want to now also properly handle failed login attempts, and there seems to be some issues here: I can't rely on `ControllerAdvice` to catch the exceptions anymore which is fine, I tried a custom `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` to do some changes... but all I could do from there was to change the actual exception being thrown.. it was still not being caught by my controller advice.

So what I'm wondering, I understand that spring security works outside of the spring mvc/advice world, so how can I catch and change the default message that is being sent to the user? (for basic auth, for form/session, this is already working fine..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom authentcation entry point that handles authentication exceptions by implementing the interface AuthenticationEntryPoint

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     AuthenticationException e) throws IOException {

        // handle the authentication exception
        // you can return json with Jackson and 
        // write it to the HttpServletResponse.
    }
}
```

---

You can then autowire it into your security config class and add the exception handling to you HttpSecurity with .exceptionHandling()

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .exceptionHandling() 
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler);
            // ... the rest of your configuration.
}
```

You can also find my details at this post.

[Customize authentication failure response in Spring Security using AuthenticationFailureHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839910/customize-authentication-failure-response-in-spring-security-using-authenticatio/42843551#42843551)

HttpSecurity doc

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html

---

EDIT:

Handling AuthenticationException will handle invalid credentials.

Handling AccessDeniedException handles method level security such as securing a method for specific roles or authorities.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I had to add it to `http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint( auth );` also, not sure if that because of my setup or not, but now it works at least.