# spring boot restful service disable Chrome login popup

Tags: spring, rest, google-chrome, authentication, spring-boot

I am building a restful web service with an Angular front end. If the users log in with wrong credentials, the Chrome browser automatically shows a login popup. I want to prevent this by responding to code 403 instead of 401.

i have review [this question][1] and it does not help with my use case. I have also tried different solutions found on google, but in all cases is stays giving 401 with the login popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newest Spring versions, the configuration to handle authentication has changed. For this reason most tutorials do not work anymore. here is the working configuration:

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            //....
            //.and()
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

CustomAuthenticationAntryPoint.java:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.debug("Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access");
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Bad credentials");
    }
}
```