# Catch and enhance LockedException and DisabledException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I use Spring Security with OAuth 2. My OAuth users have `account_locked` and `enabled` fields and I use them for different reasons. E.g. `account_locked` for blocking users and `enabled` for deactivating users. When user tries to log in and has block, then he receives `401` HTTP code and message "User account is locked". If he is deactivated, then he also receives `401` HTTP code and message "User is disabled".

I want to enhance these errors with additional information(like it is possible to enhance token using `TokenEnhancer`) to distinguish block code from deactivated code on the client. E.g. with the field `reason_of_fail`. Please note that I don't want to use text messages from these errors.

I already tried to use this(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42843551/2656632)):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authencationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)  
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);    
}
```

But these handlers doesn't catch `LockedException` and `DisabledException`.

So, how I can enhance these errors with additional field(key-value pair)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Authorization server**

If you would like to add this functionality to your authorization server, and you have a custom `AbstractTokenGranter` (see conversation below),
then you can catch the desired exceptions in the `getOAuth2Authentication` method.
You can then throw a custom exception that extends `OAuth2Exception` and populates the `additionalInformation` map with any of the additional fields you require.
For an example of how to do this you can see the [ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/7bfe08d8f95b2fec035de484068f7907851b27d0/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/password/ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java) from the spring-security-oauth project.

**Client**

If, instead, you would like to add this functionality to your OAuth2 client, then you can use a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` to catch the `LockedException` and `DisabledException`.
Here is an example security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .oauth2Login()
            .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler());
}
```

And an example of a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler`:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) {
        if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            // throw new exception or modify response
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's still the same - `onAuthenticationFailure()` just not called. But I have 3 points: 1. When I added your code,  I got `ClassNotFoundException`, then I added `spring-security-oauth2-client` in `pom` and got `Bean method 'clientRegistrationRepository' not loaded because OAuth2 Clients Configured Condition registered clients is not available`, it's [described here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12654#issuecomment-505295787). So, do I need to add these properties(duplicate them), if I already have `oauth_client_details` table with clients in my DB?

Comment: 2. These properties are not exactly the same as existing properties in the DB. In `oauth_client_details` table I have these columns:`client_id,resource_ids,client_secret,scope,authorized_grant_types,web_server_redirect_uri,authorities,access_token_validity,refresh_token_validity,additional_information,...`, but properties in `application.properties` should have another structure and fields(as it described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-client)). How should I map existing properties from DB in `application.properties`?

Comment: 3. Will the original problem be solved after solving these two points?

Comment: @don-prog The configuration that I mentioned is for the client side. Based on your comments, I now understand that you want to add this functionality to your authorization server, and not the client, is that correct? Additionally, can you share which endpoint you are receiving the 401 response from?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I receive 401 from `localhost:8443/oauth/token`

Comment: @don-prog And which grant_type are you using? Different grant types can give different error codes.

Comment: I use my custom `grant_type`s

Comment: @don-prog Do you also have custom `AbstractTokenGranter`s?

Comment: Yes, I also have custom granters.

Comment: @don-prog You can catch the desired exceptions in you `getOAuth2Authentication` method. See the [ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/7bfe08d8f95b2fec035de484068f7907851b27d0/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/password/ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java) for an example. You can then throw a custom exception that extends `OAuth2Exception` and populates the `additionalInformation` map with any of the additional fields you require.

Comment: Thanks, it's works! Please, add information from your last comment in your answer, I want to accept it.