# Change the Bad credentials error response spring security oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a AuthorizationServer which uses password grant_type using Spring Security. I am using this for a mobile application. When a user enters their username and password to log in, the app calls the token endpoint and generates a token, if they are an authenticated user. This is all handled by password grant_type itself. For an unsuccessful login, it returns below general error with 400 HTTP status code.

```json
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}
```

For my scenario I need to customize this error message. Is their a way to change this error message?

I tried the suggested duplicate question:
[Customize authentication failure response in Spring Security using AuthenticationFailureHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839910/customize-authentication-failure-response-in-spring-security-using-authenticatio),
but it uses the formLogin and it's not working with my implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize authentication failure response in Spring Security using AuthenticationFailureHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839910/customize-authentication-failure-response-in-spring-security-using-authenticatio)

Comment: Sorry @Adi I meant I am not using SSO and http.formLogin() my case, I am using grant_type password to log in users when username and password is provided via a mobile application.

Comment: check if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368896/custom-error-objects-for-spring-rest-api-and-swagger-ui/62370012#62370012 works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer to this problem for many days. Finally, I got help from one of my colleagues. He asked me to follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@beladiyahardik7/spring-security-custom-oauth2exception-in-spring-b35a62af4d34) and it worked for me. Now I could transform the default spring framework response to my response template as follows.

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Invalid username or password",
    "timestamp": "2020-06-19T10:58:29.973+00:00",
    "payload": null
 }
```

But still, we don't know, why authenticationFailure handler is not working. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sabin answer is works, but i need to throw the exception using BadCredentialsException,

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException{

        final String username = authentication.getName();
        final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        try {

            /* CHECKING USER CREDENTIAL */
            /* check account */
            User userDetail = userService.findByUsername(username);
            if (userDetail == null){
                throw new Exception("User not found!");
            }

            /* check password */
            String origPass = Utilities.getEncrypted(new String(Base64.decodeBase64(password)), username);
            if(!userDetail.getPassword().equals(origPass)){
                throw new Exception("Wrong username or password!");
            }
            
            /* check is active */
            if(!userDetail.getIsActive()){
                throw new Exception("User is not active!");
            }

            /* check allowance in web type */
            if(Access.isWeb()){
                if(!userDetail.getIsWeb())
                    throw new Exception("Web access prohibited!");
            }

            /* check allowance in mobile type */
            if(Access.isMobile()){
                if(!userDetail.getIsMobile())
                    throw new Exception("Mobile access prohibited!");
            }
            
            /* do some logs */
            userService.login(userDetail);

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetail, "{noop}".concat(origPass), userDetail.getAuthorities());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("[OAUTH] Error : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new BadCredentialsException(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the message text in the response, than it will be enough to add the **messages.properties** file to the classpath of your application with the following content:

`AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Invalid username or password`

This will lead to the response below:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid username or password"
}
```