# Custom Error Objects for Spring Rest API And Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a spring boot rest API project and I am pondering how to change the default error object returned from spring boot.

UseCase: /token api is to be called without authentication and other apis are to be called by passing a token. 
The swagger UI needs to be used for the same purpose.
Error response needs to be modified as a custom object.

eg: The default structure is like this for Unauthorised api request.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-14T05:46:37.538+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/scholarship/api/v1.0/applicant" 
}
```

I would want it to be like

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": "Unauthorised"
}
```

I have swagger ui also configured for the project.

My Config file is like this which helps me open the swagger-ui. html and i have also tried to get a handle to the Unauthorised abject in the exception handler in this but it doesn't fire.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")
    );

    AuthenticationProvider provider;

    public SecurityConfig(final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        super();
        this.provider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/token/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        log.error("in authenticationFilter");
        final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());

        //filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }


    @Autowired
    private HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver;

    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        log.error("in authenticationEntryPoint");
        return new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
            @Override
            public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                 AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                log.error("in commence");
                try {
                    log.error(authException.getLocalizedMessage());
                    handlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    throw e;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new ServletException(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Alternatively, i have a @ControllerAdvice to reformat the error object but it is also not working

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {InsufficientAuthenticationException.class})
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> authenticationException(InsufficientAuthenticationException ex) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add("Authentication is required to access this resource");
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("error", "Unauthorized", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
```

What could be possibly misconfiguration?

Update1:

If I change to this then I get my custom object when invoking the secure api, but swagger Ui is not opening and I get my custom error for swagger UI access

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated();

        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
    }
```

Error when accessing Swagger UI

```
{"status":"error","message":"Unauthorized","errors":["Authentication is required to access this resource"]}
```

Update 2:

Changing to the below opens up the Swagger UI but again the error objects are not custom then

```
 @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.error("in configure");
        http.authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
                .fullyAuthenticated();

        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
    }
```

Update 3:

The core issues lie's in configure(HttpSecurity http) method

If i add the below two lines the API's are authenticated but the error object is the default object. If I remove these lines the API are not authenticated(even if you pass the token they keep failing) but I get the custom error object.

```
.authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

Comment: remove the `throw new ServletException(e);` and add `throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(e.getMessage())`

Comment: doesnt help ..still the same

Comment: Can you ignore swagger urls in your SecurityConfig.java,
  
    `public void configure(final WebSecurity webSecurity) {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/token/**", "/swagger*/**", "/v2/api-docs", 
    "/webjars/**", "/configuration/**");
    }`

Comment: doesnt help ..still the same

Answer (score 2):

The exceptions from Servlet Filter which do not reach the controller are handled by 
`BasicErrorController`.

You need to override the `BasicErrorController` to change the default exception body thrown by spring.

How to override:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class BasicErrorControllerOverride extends AbstractErrorController {

  public BasicErrorControllerOverride(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
    super(errorAttributes);
  }

  @RequestMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpStatus status = this.getStatus(request);

    /*
       If you want to pull default error attributes and modify them, use this
       Map<String, Object> defaultErrorAttributes = this.getErrorAttributes(request, false);
    */

    Map<String, Object> errorCustomAttribute = new HashMap<>();
    errorCustomAttribute.put("status", "error");
    errorCustomAttribute.put("message", status.name());
    return new ResponseEntity(errorCustomAttribute, status);
  }

  @Override
  public String getErrorPath() {
    return "/error";
  }
}
```

How error response will look like

```
{
    "message": "UNAUTHORIZED",
    "status": "error"
}
```