# How to Customize "Bad credentials" error response in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring-cloud-oauth2 to create an authorisation server. It is based on both client credentials and Username and password. My problem is that I am not able to customise the error response for bad credentials when typing incorrect username-password. I controlled the error response for wrong client credentials by implementing the AuthenticationEntryPoint interface. Similar to that I tied to handle Bad credential response, using `AuthenticationFailureHandler` by following [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spri). But it seems like failure handler is not getting registered and so `onAuthenticationFailure` method is never getting executed. What I am trying to achieve is a solution for exactly this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942742/change-the-bad-credentials-error-response-spring-security-oauth2).

Following is a part of the relevant code:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler.class);

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("timestamp", new Date());
        data.put("exception", e.getMessage());

        httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));

    }
}
// CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler.Class
```

Following is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;



    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        // auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/jwks-json")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .httpBasic().
                and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint);

        //http.addFilterAfter(customExceptionTranslation(),ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);


    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder(){



        PasswordEncoder defaultEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put("noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

        DelegatingPasswordEncoder passworEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(
                "bcrypt", encoders);

        passworEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(defaultEncoder);

        return passworEncoder;
    }
```

Please tell me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

ng-security-custom-authentication-failure-handler

Comment: Check if the solution works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368896/custom-error-objects-for-spring-rest-api-and-swagger-ui/62370012#62370012

Comment: Sorry this seems like not working @S

Comment: have you tried removing the `                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)` from configure and then running the solution mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: I tried it now. But still, I couldn't make it. Did you know about some filter which actually gives this original response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a CustomOauthException which extends OAuth2Exception as mentioned in this link [medium blog for customising oauth response](https://medium.com/@beladiyahardik7/spring-security-custom-oauth2exception-in-spring-b35a62af4d34).Then you can customize the response given by the CustomOauthException using a custom JsonSerializer.

This  is an another approach to achieve the same use case.Though I don't know why 
`onAuthenticationFailure` isn't getting executed in the given code.

Hope this helps.